# Heatmap for multivalue variables

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am creating a heatmap using dc.js master API.  My example is based on [this](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/examples/heatmap-filtering.html).  But the major difference is that the rows and columns have multivalues.

Below is the dataset in CSV format:

```
id,city,visitor,animals,food
1,NYC,854,"Lion,Tiger,Rabbit,Ape,Zebra,Monkey,Elephant,Horse","Apple,Banana,Chicken,Egg,Fish,Grape,Ham,Ice,Juice"
2,LAX,123,"Cat,Tiger,Rabbit,Ape,Whale,Bear,Zebra,Donkey,Goat,Turtle","Apple,Banana,Cake,Fish,Sugar,Bamboo,Leaf,Ham,Ice,Water"
3,LON,584,"Lion,Tiger,Ape,Shark,Panda,Zebra,Deer,Turtle,Bear,","Apple,Coke,Cake,Fish,Bamboo,Water,Grape,Orange"
4,TOR,704,"Cat,Rabbit,Ape,Whale,Bear,Panda,Donkey,Turtle,Cheetah","Banana,Cake,Orange,Kiwi,Sugar,Bamboo,Leaf,Goat,Ice,Juice"
5,SFO,855,"Lion,Tiger,Ape,Zebra,Monkey,Elephant,Donkey,Goat,Turtle,Cheetah","Apple,Cake,Grape,Ham,Juice,Hay"
6,DAL,654,"Salmon,Penguin,Rabbit,Ape,Whale,Goat,Tortoise","Apple,Banana,Cake,Ice,Water,Earthworm"
```

Animals and food each has multiple values. The rows are based on food and the columns are based on animals.  I am able to create the heatmap but there is no interaction with other charts.  For example, if I can click on a box, there is no action in the bar chart.  The error message found at console is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined."  Here is the code.

```
parsecsv = function (string) {
    var rows = d3.csv.parse(string);
    var records = [];
    rows.forEach(function (d, i) {
        d.animals= d.animals.split(/,/);
        d.food = d.food.split(/,/);
        records.push(d)
    });
    return records
};

var chartGroup = "chartGroup";
var heatmapChart = dc.heatMap("#heatmap", chartGroup);
var pieChart1 = dc.pieChart("#piechart1", chartGroup);
var pieChart2 = dc.pieChart("#piechart2", chartGroup);  
var barChart = dc.barChart("#barchart", chartGroup);


var ndx  = crossfilter(parsecsv(csvtext));
console.log(ndx);
var animals_food_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { console.log (d.animals);return [d.animals, d.food]; });
var animals_food_group = animals_food_dim.groupAll().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial).value();

function reduceAdd(p, v) {      
    // skip empty values
  if (v.animals[0] === "" || v.food[0]==="") return p;  
  v.animals.forEach (function(val1, idx1) {
    v.food.forEach (function(val2, idx2) {
        var temp_array=[val1,val2];
        p[temp_array] = (p[temp_array] || 0) + 1; //increment counts
        //console.log(val1+":"+val2, p[temp_array],temp_array);     
    });
  });
  return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
  if (v.animals[0] === "") return p;    // skip empty values
  v.animals.forEach (function(val1, idx1) {
    v.food.forEach (function(val2, idx2) {
    var temp_array=[val1,val2];
    p[temp_array] = (p[temp_array] || 0) - 1; //increment counts
    //console.log(val1+":"+val2,p[temp_array]);     
    });
  });
  return p;  
}

function reduceInitial() {
  return {};  
}

animals_food_group.all = function() {
  var newObject = [];
  for (var key in this) {
     if (this.hasOwnProperty(key) && key != "all" && key != "top") {
        var temp_array=[key.substring(0,key.indexOf(",")),key.substring(key.indexOf(",")+1)];
        //console.log(temp_array,this[temp_array]);
        newObject.push({
            key: temp_array,
            value: this[temp_array]
        });
     }
  }
  return newObject;
};

animals_food_group.top = function(count) {
     var newObject = this.all();
    newObject.sort(function(a, b){return b.value - a.value});
     return newObject.slice(0, count);
};  

heatmapChart
    .width(12 * 80 + 80)
    .height(27 * 10 + 40)
    .dimension(animals_food_dim)
    .group(animals_food_group)
    .keyAccessor(function(d) {return d.key[0];})
    .valueAccessor(function(d)  {return d.key[1];})             
    .colorAccessor(function(d) {return +d.value;})
    .linearColors(["#FFEAEA", "#FF0000"])
    .title(function(d) {
      return "Animals:   " + d.key[0] + "\n" +
             "Food:  " + d.key[1] + "\n" +
             "Count: " + ( d.value) + " ";})        
    .calculateColorDomain();    

heatmapChart.render();

var city_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.city; });
var city_group = city_dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.visitor;});
barChart
    .dimension(city_dim)
    .group(city_group)
    .width(12 * 80 + 80)
    .height(480)
    .elasticY(true)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["NYC","LAX","LON","TOR","SFO","DAL"]))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal) 
    .elasticY(true)
    .centerBar(false)
    .xAxisPadding(50);
barChart.render();
```

I bet I must did something wrong in reduceAdd, reduceRemove and/or animals_food_group.all.  Would someone help me how to fix the interaction problem?

The JSFiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/chitester11/u33yb8k5/.